# What does this declaration in C# .net mean?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, mono

I have the following declaration in .NET. I want to know what exactly this declaration mean (the second line), especially the `DoConsoleCancelEvent`

```
delegate void InternalCancelHandler;

static readonly InternalCancelHandler cancel_handler = 
    new InternalCancelHandler (DoConsoleCancelEvent);
```

The `DoConsoleCancelEvent` is declared as:

```
internal static void DoConsoleCancelEvent{...}
```

What is the term used in .NET? Is it .NET reflection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`InternalCancelHandler` is a [`delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which is the C# way of holding a reference to a particular method. The first line defines the delegate to refer to a method that has a `void` return, and takes no parameters (since there is no parameter list.) This definition:

```
delegate int InternalCancelHandler(bool boolParam);
```

Defines a delegate that will refer to a method that returns an `int` and accepts a single `bool` parameter.

The next line is the declaration of a static, readonly field of that delegate type, which is initialized to a new instance referring to the the `DoConsoleCancelEvent` method.

With that declaration, you can now call the `DoConsoleCancelEvent` by *invoking* the delegate:

```
public static void CallDelegate()
{
    // This line will actually call DoConsoleCancelEvent
    MyType.cancel_handler();
}
```

Note that the `Handler` at the end of the delegate type suggests that it is an event handler, which means it's more likely that you'd want to use it to subscribe to an event:

```
public static void EventSub()
{
    // This line makes it so that cancel_handler is called when
    // SomeEvent is fired.  Since cancel_handler actually refers
    // to DoConsoleCancelEvent, it is *that* method that will 
    // actually be run
    SomeType.SomeEvent += cancel_handler;
}
```

`static` means that the field is associated with the `Type`, and not a particular instance of the `Type`

`readonly` means the field can only be assigned during construction of the `Type`

Comment: Well, it's *probably* a delegate... it could also be a class whose constructor accepts a delegate

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just edited the question with more detail to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Such a great answer. Very detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term you are looking for is [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

In this case, `InternalCancelHandler` is the delegate. The first line of code creates a delegate that points to your `DoConsoleCancelEvent` method. The delegate will then be used to call your method at a later point in time.

Answer (score 0):

`InternalCancelHandler` is a `delegate`.

According to a [Mono commit](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aWSUd-bs-vGoJ%3alists.ximian.com/archives/public/mono-patches/2010-November/178960.html%20DoConsoleCancelEvent&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com), this is what it says about `DoConsoleCancelEvent`:

> Adds a call to the Win32 function SetConsoleCtrlHandler for Windows,
>   which adds the DoWindowsConsoleCancelEvent wrapper for
>   DoConsoleCancelEvent to the Ctrl-C handler when an event handler is
>   added, and removes the handler once all event handlers are removed.